# Section information from a JSON Object in a section

Tags: javascript, json

I find this quite hard to explain as you can see in the title but let's say this is how my object looks like,

```
{  
   "success":true,
   "objects":[  
      {  
         "name":"Stick",
         "value":"wood",
         "size":"large"
      }...
    ]
}
```

Now I'm trying to get all the data where the objects name is Stick, so basically if it's "name" is stick it should return, name, value and size.

Comment: So you want, say, an array of all the objects with `name` equal to "Stick"?

Comment: @jakeehoffmann there are multiple "objects" in this Object, there's stick, rock, pie. Now what I'd like is whenever an "objects" its "name" equals Stick then it should give me all the information stored there, which in this case is "value" and "size"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do given the constraints you've laid out.

```js
yourObject = {  
   "success":true,
   "objects":[  
      {  
         "name":"Stick",
         "value":"wood",
         "size":"large"
      },
      {
         "name":"another",
         "value":"object",
         "size":"kindaBig"
      },
      {
         "name":"Rock",
         "value":"mineral",
         "size":"huge"  
      }  
    ]
};

arr = yourObject.objects.filter((innerObject) => innerObject.name === "Stick");

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ES5 you can use map and filter as this:

```
var obj = {  
     "success":true,
     "objects":[  
        {  
           "name":"Stick",
           "value":"wood",
           "size":"large"
        }
     ]
}.objects
 .filter(function(object) {return object.name === "Stick"})
 .map(function(object) {return {value: object.value, size: object.size}})
```